# Make slider li items be clicked one after the other

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a slider, that I want to auto-slide.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.navigation li').trigger('click');
}, 100);
```

This code made it move, but the click is always performed on the first li item, so the 3rd slides never show. How can I make it click all of them and start over again automatically, lets say "loop"?

Check this link to see how the slider is behaving with this code...

http://goo.gl/MX6WjD

Comment: Please check the answers below, comment, voteup helpfull answers, and mark the answer as correct if it really what you looking for.

Comment: it did not work, i tried both... the slider does not auto-slide, it did slide with my code but only loops between 1 and 2 instead of going trough all the li items. adde a live link to the live test so you can see how the slider behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to loop through all the `li`s using selector `eq()` with index wile the length of `li`s reached :

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){

        var slide_count = $('.navigation li').length;
        var cpt=0;

        setInterval(function() 
        {
            if( cpt < slide_count )
            {
                $('.navigation li:eq('+cpt+')').click();

                cpt++;
            }else{
                cpt=0;
            }
        }, 2000);

    }, 1000);

});
```

**[Live Example](http://acharki.byethost4.com/PrismEffectSlider/index.html)** (Loop slide every 2 seconds).

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks,  did not work, I have added a link to the sample site so you can understand better what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` since `setInterval()` would set another timeout after running which would create an inconsistency in the wait period. `setTimeout()` code executes in the exact time period defined.

The following code would initiate a click on every `li` on the exact timeperiod defined. Here the time out is set to 4 sec, but you may set it based on your need.

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>

<script>
$().ready(function(){
var totalEle = $('.navigation li').length;
var currentElement = 0;
var transitionTime = 4000; // 4 sec

function Transition()
{
    setTimeout(function() {    
    alert("Image " + $('.navigation li').eq(currentElement).text() + " was clicked");   
    currentElement < (totalEle - 1) ? currentElement++ : currentElement = 0;
           Transition();        
    }, transitionTime); 
}

Transition(); 
});
   </script>
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/rLanzn2w/17/

Comment: did not work, I have added a link to the sample site so you can understand better what I want to achieve.